# Is the 'Reveal transition' effect from Activity 1 to Activity 2 on Pre Lollipop possible?

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

[Reveal Transition like this](https://developer.android.com/design/material/videos/ContactsAnim.mp4)

Ques 1: Is it possible to have exactly the above kind of screen transition on pre lollipop versions?

Ques2: Can someone help me to achieve this animation through some sample code or example?

Comment: It is extremely difficult to do this pre-lollipop and it is very fragile. It is possible to do this using the technique that Chet Haase describes in his devbyte here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPxkoe2MraA but any kind of activity change (orientation change or data change, for example) will break it. If you need that kind of animation, you can do it yourself with animations within an Activity.

Comment: Ok Cool! So if i want to do the same thing on lollipop and above, can you suggest me an example with exactly the same animations? I belive that one is the slide animation. The other two are explode and fade.

Comment: That is a very complex transition. There are 2 shared elements: the text and the image. The text changes size and color. You'll have to do something a little custom to do text size and color changes. The enter and exit transitions are a combination of slide and fade.